# I cannot delete a collection in cloud Firestore fron the console

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-console

I cannot delete a collection in cloud firestore from the console. When I try to do it I get the message in the capture below.

I'm project owner on the project hosting firestore.

Best regards,
[image]

Comment: Are there any documents that were deleted in your attempt?

Comment: I dont know how many documents were there before the attempt so I cannot tell you. But I dont think so.

Comment: Are you on the free plan?

Comment: Nope I'm not : I dont have the free tier status icon (gift box) on the upper right corner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after 2 days of a this not working delete, I tried a while ago and the delete was successful. I did nothing special. I imagine this what we can encounter when we work on beta features from Google Cloud.